# My href onclick event is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

As a part of a project in my job, I'm trying to do a very simple Image Slider.

I made a function that should make the slide but the problem is when I click on the arrows, it's not changing the image to the next/prev one.

Here's my code:

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Photo Slider</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">


      <!--Left Arrow-->
      <div class="arrow">
          <a href="#" onclick="slide(-1)">
              <span class="left"></span>
          </a> 
      </div>

      <!--Image-->
      <img src="images/img1.jpg" class="img" />

      <!--Right Arrow-->
      <div class="arrow">
          <a href="#" onclick="slide(1)">
              <span class="right"></span>
          </a>
      </div>



  </div> 
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

## JS:

```
var imageCount = 1;
var total = 5;
function slide(x)
{
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
    imageCount += x;
    if (imageCount > total || imageCount < 1)
        imageCount = 1;
    image.src = "images/img" + imageCount + ".jpg";
}
```

## CSS:

```
.container {
    width:700px;
    height:600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position:relative;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  width:3em;
}



a {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align:center;
}

a:hover .left, a:hover .top, a:hover .bottom, a:hover .right{
  border: 0.3em solid #e74c3c;
}

a:hover .left:after, a:hover .top:after, a:hover .bottom:after, a:hover .right:after {
  border-top: 0.3em solid #e74c3c;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #e74c3c;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    border: 0.3em solid #333;
    border-radius: 50%;
    /* margin-right: -3.5em; */
    /* margin-left: 0em; */
    /* margin: auto 0; */
}

.left:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.7em;
    margin-left: 0.6em;
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 1.4em;
    border-top: 0.3em solid #333;
    border-right: 0.3em solid #333;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 0.3em solid #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 40.1em;
}

.right:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0.7em;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
  width: 1.4em;
  height: 1.4em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #333;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #333;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


.img {
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:14%;

}
```

How can I make it work? What did I do wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a *collection* of elements. Therefore, `image.src` will fail because element collections do not expose an `src` property.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array so you should write :

```
image[0].src = "images/img" + imageCount + ".jpg";
```

## [CodePen](http://codepen.io/bugyt/pen/xVqzxV)

Comment: Shouldn't `0` in `image[0]` be a variable as you will have to access a different image in the array on each click?

Comment: If you have only one image with the class `img` on your page, it will always be 0.

Comment: But he's making an image slider, the example has one slide, but I'm sure there will be more in the future. Otherwise, what's the point of _prev_ and _next_ buttons if there's only one slide?

Comment: @hungerstar but only one image displayed at a time

Comment: Silly me, I forgot we were changing the `src` attribute for this slider, sorry. I had it in my head there would be additional `img` markup like most sliders.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];
```

As `document.getElementsByClassName('img')` returns an collection you need reference the first item in this collection, which is done with `[0]`. This collection is similar to an array but there are some differences -- [see here if interested](http://xahlee.info/js/js_array_vs_nodelist_vs_html_collection.html)

Alternatively, as an html page can only have one id, if you set the `id` of the image to `img` you can then simply do:

```
 <img src="images/img1.jpg" id="img" />
```

You could do

```
var image = document.getElementById('img');
```

Comment: Accessing the array should be done via a variable referencing the proper index in the array instead of a hard coded `0` should it not?

Comment: @hungerstar can you elaborate? As there is only one element with class name of `img` this will always be accessed with `[0]`. Perhaps I am missing what you mean, but please explain as I am eager to learn

Comment: Silly me, I forgot we were changing the `src` attribute for this slider, sorry. I had it in my head there would be additional `img` markup like most sliders.